# Serving react-routes with Express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom and load components on rotes like this:

```
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/services" component={Services} />
        ...and so on...
        <Route component={PageNotFound} />
    </Switch>
```

I build this project with webpack and have only 1 single file bundle.js. and use It as static files in my server.js

```
import express from 'express'
const app = express()
app.use('/', express.static('./public'))
app.listen(3000)
```

Eveything works fine until I start trying to do something on some of my routes:

```
app.get('/services', () => {
  console.log('services')
})
```

When I'm on route '/services' it doesn't log 'services' in console.

Comment: not sure if this is why, but you have a typo in your question - `services` and `/serives`

Comment: Basically they are two completely different routes, from two different servers. You need to tell your `express` server about your `react` service route. `app.get('/services')` will try to query an `express` back-end route, while you are trying to access a `react` front-end route.

Comment: DrunkDevKek, is there any way to tell express about my front-end sever?

Comment: you will need to have the back-end routing to get before the static serving. in short backend route first before serving react

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between the browser rendering the route and Express rendering a path. They are two completely different things. When you refresh the browser, Express does not know how to handle "/services", therefore you get an error. When you type "/api/services" then express does know how to handle the path. When React/React-Router is fully loaded into the browser, it does not request "/services" from the Express server, the browser already knows about the router, and renders the HTML.

You need a wildcard route match "*" that will render the default/index.html file. This will allow your browser to locate the "/services" page. This is complicated but basically, your browser calls "/services", this hits express, who tries to find a path match. If you have a wild card that points to your index.html page, then this is returned to the browser. The Browser then looks at the route "/services" and passed this to React Router, who then load the services components.
You are always returning the same HTML (index/default), it's the browser that does the magic of showing the right page. this is why it's important to have different paths/routes (Path: "/api/services", route: "/services".

If you didn't then a user refreshing the page on the "/services" route would hit express and get the "/services" path.

Path: An Express pattern match for the URL to a  block of code "/api/services"

route: A ReactRouter URL for rendering a given Component

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your backend route is different otherwise this gets confusing.

```
app.get('/api/services', () => {
  console.log('services')
})
```

This way we know that:

/services = Your React-router component

/api/services = an API call to the backend

Comment: I tried this - doesn't work. But I noticed one thing: when I use your code with route '/api/services', and then I paste 'http://localhost:3000/services' in URL field by my hand I get 'Cannot GET /services' message in my browser and nothing in my terminal. And when I use my code with route '/services' and do the same thing it types 'services in terminal' (not in the browser's console) and trying to refresh the page. It looks strange.